# How to bind data from SQLite database to picker Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, sqlite

I got the data from my SQLite Database I want to bind the data i got to my picker.How can I bind the data to picker? Below is the Contacts table and function

> Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Retailer}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding RetailerName}"

```
[Table("tblContacts")]
public class ContactsTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, MaxLength(100)]
    public string ContactID { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(80)]
    public string FileAs { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

 public FieldActivityForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = new FieldActivityFormViewModel();
        tpTime.Time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        SetRetailerPicker();
    }

    public void SetRetailerPicker()
    {
        var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
        var conn = db.GetConnection();

        var getUser = conn.QueryAsync<ContactsTable>("SELECT FileAs FROM tblContacts");
        var resultCount = getUser.Result.Count;

        if (resultCount < 1)
        {
            //MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Http", Retailer);
        }
        else
        {
            var result = getUser.Result;
            myPicker.ItemsSource = result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: the picker's ItemSource needs to be a collection of data, not a single value.  And if you're binding ItemsSource, then manually adding Items to the Picker is redundant.  See: https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Can you revise my code? to bind the data to my picker? I've been browsing and trying different codes still I can't get the data to bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your XAML

```
<Picker x:Name="myPicker" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding RetailerName}" />
```

in the code behind, after loading the data

```
myPicker.ItemsSource = result;
```

this assumes ContactsTable is an IEnumerable that contains a property RetailerName

Comment: "after loading the data" - I presume so.  It's YOUR code, you should know.

Comment: I am getting an error when I click the picker "Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference"

Comment: does result have data?  Is it an IEnumerable?  Does it contain a property RetailerName?

Comment: you haven't answered any of my questions

Comment: the data inside result variable is "Count=416" not the actual data

Comment: So it does have data, and it sounds like it's an enumerable.  Is it of type ContactsTable, and what does that class look like?

Comment: a. that class has no property RetailerName,  b. you are only selecting a single column in your db query

Comment: a. How can get the data and bind it properly? b. I only need that specific column's data inside my picker

Comment: if that's the data you want in your Picker, then why aren't you binding to "FileAs"?  I have no idea what "RetailerName" is or where you get it from.

Comment: I am so confused right now can you show me your code and I will analyze please?

Comment: I don't have any code.  This is your code, not mine.  I suggest you download the bindable picker sample and run it and debug the code to see how it works.

Comment: I changed the binding name to FileAs and it worked but why?

Comment: because ItemDisplayBinding is the name of the property to display in your picker.  You had it set to "RetailerName" which is not even a property of your ContactsTable.  "FileAs" is a property, and is the only one in the class that actually contains any data.

Comment: How can i send "FileAs" to entry?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853271/bind-data-from-sqlite-database-to-entry-xamarin-forms