# Bind data from SQLite Database to Entry Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite

I want to get the data of **PresAddress column** in SQLite Database. I want to get the "**PresAddress**" column data and bind that data to my entry field. PresAddress is inside tblContacts. How can I get that?

Here is my code:

```
private void rcodePicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pickedRetailerCode = rcodePicker.Items[rcodePicker.SelectedIndex];

        var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
        var conn = db.GetConnection();

        var getUser = conn.QueryAsync<ContactsTable>("SELECT * FROM tblContacts WHERE ContactID=?", pickedRetailerCode);
        var resultCount = getUser.Result.Count;

        if (resultCount < 1)
        {
            //MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Http", Retailer);
        }
        else
        {
            var result = getUser.Result;
            entStreet.Text = ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++)
 {
    var result = getUser.Result[i];
    entStreet.Text = result.PresAddress;
    entBarangay.Text = result.PresBarangay;
    entCity.Text = result.PresTown;
    entProvince.Text = result.PresProvince;
    entDistributor.Text = result.PresDistrict;
 }
```